# Aggregate by $geonear

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, geospatial, geojson

I've got a collection that looks like this :

```
[
  {
    "roadname": "foo",
    "data": [
      {
        "val": 50,
        "loc": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [3.197033554, 50.64611712]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "val": NULL,
        "loc": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [3.197740735, 50.6460058]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "roadname": "foo",
    "data": [
      {
        "val": 50,
        "loc": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [3.32456512, 50.2744516]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "roadname": "bar",
    "data": [
      {
        "val": 145,
        "loc": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [3.198408689, 50.64586985]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm displaying every `data.loc` on a map, and that leads me to this :
[image: dispatched points]. (Point color represent the `val` field)

**EDIT3:** To clarify my database structure, here is a representation of the exact database. Each *gray line* represent a root element from the provided dataset :
[image: lines points]

I would like to "*group point that are near (using `data.loc`), and have the same parent `name`*" , and aggregate their `val` (say in a **average** to make it simple), in order to display something like this :
[image: aggregated points]

**EDIT3:** It's important to understand that the points I'm trying to aggregate **don't share any common property or ancestors. Their *ONLY* common denomitator is their spatial proximity**

I know `near`, `geonear` and `group` aggregation, but I'm just not able to find a solution to do this.

I'd like to use a pure mongodb solution. If it's not possible, I could use [turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) or another library also, but I'm just struggling at finding a viable and scalable way to do this.

---

**EDIT:** The main root elements on the collection represent a road, so all the points on a road have all the same parent `roadname`.

---

**EDIT2:** Data can be found **[here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cyrilchapon/020b122733034bdaa73692f9e0c289d9/raw/6ee6a5b9e62b100cf08eb061cf0a71a577f42595/aggregatingpointsdata.json)**

Comment: In the picture you provided, would all those points on the road fall under one `"data"` slot?

Comment: Hey Corey. No. Their only common thing is that parent roadname

Comment: Would these clusters fall under one data slot while there would be multiple docs/clusters with the same road name?

Comment: @Corey, no. I need to aggregate **accross** data. Actualy one root element is a "survey" and I'm trying to aggregate those surveys point by point.

Comment: Even better could you share a snippet of a sample dataset? Maybe just the points that are shown in the picture you shared.

Comment: Hum this is much data. I'm going to try.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a lot, maybe just a couple cluster of points would be fine.

Comment: Here. Edited. at the end =)

Comment: Also, FYI here we're talking about a clustering lib on turf.js repo => https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues/33#issuecomment-263825332.

But this would be js processing. I'd prefer mongo aggregations for performance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is going to work for you. I imported your dataset [aggregatingpointsdata.json](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cyrilchapon/020b122733034bdaa73692f9e0c289d9/raw/6ee6a5b9e62b100cf08eb061cf0a71a577f42595/aggregatingpointsdata.json) into a mongo collection called `roads`.

This is what one cluster would look like in mongo. So, each document represents a cluster, or one element in your array from the dataset you provided. One thing to keep in mind is that this will only work if there is some identifier for a cluster of points that should be grouped together. In my example, it is the `_id`.

```
> db.roads.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("583ee50bd7c4d711d45c7757"),
        "roadname" : "RD700",
        "data" : [
                {
                        "val" : null,
                        "loc" : {
                                "type" : "Point",
                                "coordinates" : [
                                        3.197033554,
                                        50.64611712
                                ]
                        }
                },
                {
                        "val" : null,
                        "loc" : {
                                "type" : "Point",
                                "coordinates" : [
                                        3.197740735,
                                        50.6460058
                                ]
                        }
                },
                {
                        "val" : 145,
                        "loc" : {
                                "type" : "Point",
                                "coordinates" : [
                                        3.198408689,
                                        50.64586985
                                ]
                        }
                },
          ]
}
```

This is the mongo aggregation you can run that will return an average of each cluster. I even made it to return the same GeoJSON format.

```
db.roads.aggregate([
    //unravel the cluster here
    { $unwind: "$data" },
    //project the coordinates to more readable names while preserving roadname and GeoJSON type.
    { $project: {roadname: 1, type: "$data.loc.type", val : "$data.val", lng: { $arrayElemAt: ["$data.loc.coordinates",0]}, lat: { $arrayElemAt: ["$data.loc.coordinates",-1]}}},
    //group on cluster id while preserving type and roadname. Take avergae of value, lat and long.
    { $group: { _id : "$_id", roadname: {$first:"$roadname"}, type: {$first: "$type"}, avgLng: { $avg: "$lng" },avgLat: { $avg: "$lat" }, avgVal: { $avg : "$val" }}},
    //re-project to fit the similar format of original collection
    { $project: { _id: 1, roadname: 1,  data : { val: "$avgVal", loc: {type : "$type", coordinates: ["$avgLng", "$avgLat"]}} }}
])
```

You can also add an extra `$out` to the end of the aggregation pipeline to move all these averaged centroids to another more manageable collection.

Here is what the results look like after the aggregration pipeline call shown above.

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("583ee50bd7c4d711d45c775c"),
    "roadname": "RD700",
    "data": {
      "val": 144.03703703703704,
      "loc": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          3.2232721289257142,
          50.67602178708569
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("583ee50bd7c4d711d45c775b"),
    "roadname": "RD700",
    "data": {
      "val": 170.0344827586207,
      "loc": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          3.22367598656322,
          50.67626952408046
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: If each document does NOT represent a cluster and points are all over the place, then I can come up with something else that will fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for providing a possible solution, with so much work and reflexion. However I'm sorry, I think I mislead you with the question.
One document in my dataset represent a survey along a whole road, not a "group of point within an area of the road". I mean one root element from my dataset would be a "line", not a bunch of points inside an area. The multiple root elements from my dataset form, say, "parallel" lines that I want to chunk with something like a "radius"... Like a group of points ACROSS those lines, grouped geospatialy :/

Comment: Ok, so the only way it could work with the data you have now is some complicated way the involves `geoNear` with multiple queries. I would say the best route would be to cluster them upon ingestion of the surveyed data. So, you would have some routine that would iterate over each point in the survey, then find the closest point to it in mongo, then re-average that and replace the closest point with the new average. You will be left with only the averaged data points. How far along are you development?

Comment: Hey @Corey. Thanks for your time. We're not that far, and relatively free about options. However we're importing data "survey by survey" (gray lines). We were indeed thinking of batch - processing it, but before taking care of performance, we'd like to basicaly find any working and fitting strategy. The need is simply to aggregates points by a distance factor (plus a common field containing a string)